# Upgrade from Heroku Hobby to Standard and retroactive Postgres DB rollback possible?

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

Becuase of reasons beyond our/my control we need to roll back our Postgres DB that was in the Postgres Hobby tier.

However, rollback (4 days) is not offered in Hobby, but on the next level, Postgres Standard tier.

My questions are will an upgrade perform allow me to access "retroactive" backups (if any) or is the Hobby tier totally void of any backups/data at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading your database will give you the ability to complete a point-in-time recovery only as far back as the time you upgraded or the length provided by that database plan (whichever is longer). To answer your question, no. upgrading will not let you perform a 'retroactive' rollback since you'll be dealing with an entirely new database.

Answer (score 1):

You can do manual or automatic backups to the hobby database tier. Daily backups are automatically scheduled. Backups are quite limited in the hobby tier but I have successfully used them in the past. To see your backups, use `heroku pg:backups`. Please see the guide:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-backups

Comment: This doesn't answer the original question. OP is asking about rollback functionality.